# Programming novice: How to program my own data compression algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, compression

It is summer, and so I have decided to take it upon myself to write a data-compression program, preferably in C code. I have a decent beginners understanding of how compression works. I just have a few questions:

1) Would c be a suitable programming language to accomplish this task?
2) Should I be working in byte's with the input file? Or at a binary level somehow?

If someone could just give me a nudge in the correct direction, I'd really appreciate it. I would like to code this myself however, and not use a pre-existing compression library or anything like that.

Comment: @Doug chamberlain It's fun and educational.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Have a look at the algorithm for Huffman coding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding This should be a good example algorithm to help you get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Would c be a suitable programming language to accomplish this task?

Yes.

> 2) Should I be working in byte's with the input file? Or at a binary level somehow?

They're the same, so the question makes no sense.

> not use a pre-existing compression library

Can you use a pre-existing compression algorithm?  There are dozens and "compression algorithm"  -- when used with Google -- will reveal a great deal of helpful information.

Comment: I refered to working with bytes, as opposed to somehow managing smaller groups of bits on a lower level. I have read about Huffman compression and it seems to work with individual bits unless I am understanding it wrong.

Comment: @araisbec: Bits are always collected into bytes.  There's nothing more fine-grained than bytes.  Your algorithm may be manipulating bits; but it  does this by accessing, modifying and storing whole bytes worth of bits.

Answer (score 9):

You could start by looking at [Huffman Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). A lot of computer science [classes](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/poop/huff/info/) implement that as a project so it should be manageable.  C would be appropriate for Huffman encoding, but it might be easier to do it first in a higher-level language so that you understand the concepts.There are slides, hints, and an example project [available](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit594-2011/index.html) in Java for a masters-level project at the University of Pennsylvania (search for "huff" on that page).

Answer (score 7):

To answer your questions:

1. C is suitable.
2. It depends on the algorithm, or the way you are thinking about `compression'.

My opinion will be, first decide whether you want to do a `lossless compression` or a `lossy compression`, then pick an algorithm to implement. Here are a few pointers:

For the lossless one, some are very intuitive, such as the `run-length` encoding,
e.g., if there is 11 `a`s and 5 `b`s, you just encode them as `11a5b`.
Some algorithms use a `dictionary`, please refer to `LZW encoding`. 
Finally, I do recommend `Huffman` encoding since it is very straight-forward, simple and helpful to gain experience in learning algorithm (for your educational purpose).

For lossy ones, `Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)`, or `wavelet`, is used in JPEG compression. This is useful to understand multimedia compression.

Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_algorithm) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, C is well suited for this kind of work.
2. Whether you work with bytes or bits will depend on the algorithm that you decide to implement. For example, Huffman coding is inherently bit-oriented whereas many other compression algorithms are not.

Answer (score 3):

1. C is a great choice for writing a compression program.  You can use plenty of other languages too, though.
2. Your computer probably can't directly address units of memory smaller than a byte (pretty much by definition), so working with bytes is probably a good choice.  Some of how you work with the data will be affected by the compression algorithm you choose.

Good luck!